# Using Linq to order lists within a list

Tags: list, linq, sublist

I have a list of items (actually an IEnumerable). Each item has a list of values. For example:

```
Item1.Value[0] = "Health & Safety"
Item1.Value[1] = "Economic"
Item1.Value[2] = "Environment"

Item2.Value[0] = "Reputation"
Item2.Value[1] = "Environment"
Item2.Value[2] = "Regulatory"

...
```

How can I order the list of values using linq? I know I can order the list of items using something like:

Items.Orderby(x => x.something)

...but how do I get to the list of values in each item?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Items.ForEach(i=> x.something = x.something.OrderBy(o=> o.field));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based off OP's comment, `Value` is a `Dictionary<string, object>`. You cannot sort a `Dictionary` as they are unordered by design.

Consider using a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=VS.100).aspx), and implement an [`IComparer<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.100).aspx) to fit your sorting needs:

---

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "b", 1 }, { "a", 2 }, { "c", 3 }
};

// { { "a", 2 }, { "b", 1 }, { "c", 3 } }
SortedDictionary<string, object> keyAscending =
    new SortedDictionary<string, object>(values);

public class ReverseStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return y.CompareTo(x);
    }
}

// { { "c", 3 }, { "b", 1 }, { "a", 2 } }
SortedDictionary<string, object> keyDescending =
    new SortedDictionary<string, object>(values, new ReverseStringComparer());
```

Comment: Actually, Value is a dictionary where the key is a string and the value is an object. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to do anything: items.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Values.OrderBy(y => y.Key)).

Comment: Updated my answer, you may want to consider using a `SortedDictionary`.